# SSRS Exporting to Excel - Use different filename?

Tags: reporting-services

Not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to export an SSRS report to Excel under a *different* filename than the report filename.

For example, the report is MyReport.rdl. When I export, it outputs the Excel file as MyReport.xlsx. I'd like to use a different filename for the Excel file. Is there a property that allows me to do this?

SSRS 2012

Answer (score 1):

Set the 'DisplayName' property in your RDL file to the export filename you would like.

Comment: I don't see the DisplayName property anywhere.

Comment: The displayname property is only used if you are using the report viewer control, are you using this control?

Answer (score 0):

While saving the report to excel, you can give any name you want.

Please check the attached screen shots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but we have .NET code that pulls several reports at once automatically into a zip file, so this Save As dialog is not present.